# python loading several matlab files

Tags: python, matlab, file, loops, file-io

I was wondering of how I can load several matlab files in python. I am very new to python and don't know much

I am using `scipy.io.loadmat('/~/20130228_100000_3D_E=1.mat')` and then I save the data in .vts format

How can I do this with all the available matlab files I have by running my program only once?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all the `.mat` files are in the same directory, you could do this:

```
import os

dataDir = "/some/folder/containing/data/"
mats = []
for file in os.listdir( dataDir ) :
    mats.append( scipy.io.loadmat( dataDir+file ) )
```

You would then have all the matlab files in a list (like arrays in other languages), you can get at them by:

```
mats[0]
mats[1]
...
```